# JavaScript: Getting fully-qualified function name from within it?

Tags: javascript, reflection, naming

Take a look at the snippet below. Is there any function I could write in replace of `...` to generate the route, that could reused in another function? Something like `var route = this.show.fullyQualifiedName` perhaps?

```
var services = {
    'github.com': {
        api: {
            v2: {
                json: {
                    repos: {
                        show: function(username, fn) {
                            var route = ...; 
                            // route now == 'github.com/api/v2/json/repos/show'

                            route += '/' + username;

                            return $.getJSON('http://' + route).done(fn);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not think a top-down search is possible. How will the search know when it's found its match unless I've provided it with the full path of `show`? And if I've provided it with the full path of `show`, that defeats the point of use a single function o get `route` values from inside any method like `show` I define.

Comment: you'd have to recursively fill the tree (just once) _before_ ever calling the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't, at least not using "reflection" style operations.

Objects have no knowledge of the name of the objects in which they're contained, not least because the same object (reference) could be contained within *many* objects.

The only way you could do it would be to start at the top object and work your way inwards, e.g.:

```
function fillRoutes(obj) {
    var route = obj._route || '';
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (key === '_route') continue;
        var next = obj[key];
        next._route = route + '/' + key;
        fillRoutes(next);
    }
}
```

which will put a new `_route` property in each object that contains that object's path.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/WbMfW/

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a recursive search, like **Alnitak** said, but you could do a top-down search, although it could be somewhat slow depending on the size of your object. You'd loop through the object's properties, checking to see if it has children. If it does have a child, loop through that, etc. When you reach the end of a chain and you haven't found your function, move to the next child and continue the search.

Don't have the time to write up an example now, but hopefully you can piece something together from this.