# Infinite loop when attempting to search an object

Tags: javascript

I recently saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10355185/339852) being asked in which the OP wanted to find the path to a property of an object, so I answered it in psuedocode, stating that I didn't have enough time to actually write a solution. However, the question was so interesting to me that I wound up attempting to write a solution anyways. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function Node(obj, parent, searchTarget) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.obj = obj;
    this.searchTarget = searchTarget;

    this.searchNode = function() {
        if(this.obj == this.searchTarget) {

            //return this.reconstructPathRecursive();
        }

        if (!isEmpty(this.obj)) {
            var children = [];

            for (prop in this.obj) {
                if (this.obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    children.push(new Node(this.obj[prop], this, searchTarget));
                }
            }

            var path;
            for(var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
                path = children[i].searchNode();
                if(path) return path;
            }
        }
    }

    this.reconstructPathRecursive = function() {
        var path = [this], curObj = this.parent;

        while (curObj != undefined) {
            path.push(curObj);
            curObj = curObj.parent;
            if(curObj == undefined) break;
        }

        return path;
    }

    this.findPath = function() {
        return this.searchNode();
    }
}

var myObj = {
    nullRoot: "gotcha!",
    path1: {
        myFunc: function() {
            alert("Success!");
        }
    }
}

function findFunctionPath(obj, func) {
    return new Node(obj, undefined, func).findPath();
}
var thisFunc = myObj.path1.myFunc;
    console.log("--");

console.log(findFunctionPath(myObj, thisFunc));
```

The idea is that I would call `this.searchNode()` on Node objects which represented each of the object's properties. `searchNode()` would call itself on each of the resulting property nodes, passing in the current object as the `parent` on each of the children nodes. If I found the function to search for, I would call `reconstructPathRecursive()`, which pretty much does that, using the parent property on each of the nodes.

However, I get a 'Maximum call stack size exceeded.' error when I run this [live test](http://jsfiddle.net/HeyJavascript/yc2VN/10/). I assume it means I accidentally wrote an infinite loop somehow. Where's the flaw in my logic, and where did that infinite loop sneak in? `console.log` shows that `searchNode` is being called over and over again, whereas I'm only calling it if the object isn't empty, and I'm not giving the object a reference to itself anywhere (I don't think...), so I'm really kind of stumped here.

**Edit:** I updated the code somewhat to change `isEmpty` from a Node function to a global function, so that I could call it on `this.obj` in the `searchNode()` function. Previously, it would only call it on Nodes (which will always have at least two properties, thus resulting in an infinite loop), not the objects the referenced. That's fixed, but the error persists.

**Another edit**: Found and corrected another error (see Satyajit's answer). Still getting the infinite loop, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fail on

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = arr;
```

because it contains itself as a child.  The `Node` function ends up creating an unbounded list of nodes where the parent is the same as the child.

To handle cyclic object graphs, you need to keep track of what you've already visited and avoid revisiting it.  This is difficult in JavaScript because you don't have object sets.

You can either keep a list of objects you've visited, and check whether `obj` appears in it, or you could try to use a special object property (*breadcrumb*) to tell whether you've visited an object.  The breadcrumb fails if you don't clean up properly or someone else uses that property, or other code uses EcmaScript 5 freezing.

---

EDIT:

You should also break out of the child loop when you actually find a path in a child.

> ```
> path = children[i].searchNode();
> ```

should be

```
 path = children[i].searchNode();
 if (path) { return path; }
```

---

EDIT:

As Satyajit points out, `"gotcha"` is a property value.

Since `"gotcha"[0] === "g"` and `"g"[0] === "g"` it doesn't take long before you reach a cycle.

When I do

```
alert("gotcha".hasOwnProperty(0));
for (var k in "gotcha") { alert(k); }
```

in a recent Chrome, I get alerts "true", "0", "1", ..., "5".

This is standard behavior on modern browsers as outlined in section [15.5.5.2](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.5.2):

> String objects use a variation of the [[GetOwnProperty]] internal method used for other native ECMAScript objects (8.12.1). This special internal method is used to add access for named properties corresponding to individual characters of String objects.

and these properties are enumerable due to bullet 9 in that section.

Comment: Could you elaborate on where I'm doing that, please? I don't see anywhere I am. I'll see how I can implement keeping track of what I've already visited. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, the problem is that `myObj` is cyclic.  You don't show how `myObj` is derived so I can't point you at the code.

Comment: Did you visit the jsFiddle I provided? Updating the link to it now. Also, myObj is just another object. You see how it's derived. It's just a test object so I can test my function on it.

Comment: `searchNode()` is called only on the children of each child (or the main object, if we're at the top level). I don't have any references to a parent anywhere else (that I do anything with, that is), so I shouldn't need a cyclic graph, correct?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, as Satyajit explains, the value of property 0 of `'g'` is `'g'` so it is a cyclic graph.

Comment: Hang on a tic, where are you getting `'g'` from? Could you elaborate just a little more? My console logged `'g'` as well, although I certainly didn't set any properties called `'g'` anywhere.

Comment: Oh, wait, `'g'` as in the first letter of "gotcha"? Are characters in a string treated as properties, by any chance? I think I might see what's going wrong. Mind=Blown.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, yep.  At least on modern browsers.  The [language spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.5.2) says "This special internal method is used to add access for named properties corresponding to individual characters of String objects." and later in that same section "8. Let resultStr be a String of length 1, containing one character from str, specifically the character at position index, where the first (leftmost) character in str is considered to be at position 0, the next one at position 1, and so on."

Comment: Oho, that clears things up. Thanks a lot, that seems to have broken the infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

The property `nullRoot` is a string and not a javascript object. Running your `isEmpty` function on that will never return false and throw it into an infinite loop. It's almost prophetic that you put "gotcha" as its value though.

Comment: I actually just caught that a minute ago, just forgot to update my answer (no, it didn't solve my problem). And yes, I put "gotcha" because I know it would probably get me somewhere down the line... :)

Comment: Nice catch.  It didn't occur to me that a non-empty string was a cyclic object since `"g"[0] === "g"` until you pointed out the `isEmpty` behavior.